# How do you efficiently manage texture memory in OpenGLES on Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, android-memory

I am loading textures into OpenGLES on Android and maintaining a reference to the generated `id` in a HashMap.

At a given point in time not all textures that have been loaded will be in use, but may be used at a later point in time, therefore if the device has enough free memory I'd like to keep the textures loaded.

However, if the device starts running low on memory I would like to delete any textures that are not in use since they can always be reloaded later if they're required.

I've tried a few methodologies for handling this scenario.

***1. Respond to system memory warnings***

If the application receives a memory warning, then it will identify which textures are not in use and schedule for those textures to be deleted.

This method did work reasonably well.

***2. Use Soft References***

In this approach the application would maintain a `List<SoftReference<Texture>>` where the `Texture` class is a wrapper around the `id` that was returned when a given texture was loaded into OpenGLES.

If a given `Texture` is not in use at a given point in time then only a `SoftReference` would exist to this `Texture` and thus if the garbage collector deemed it necessary it could reclaim this memory and the `finalize` method on the `Texture` class would schedule for this texture to be deleted.

This approach seemed ideal based upon the description of `SoftReference` in the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html), since they would only be reclaimed when more memory was required.

> Soft reference objects, which are cleared at the discretion of the garbage collector in response to memory demand. Soft references are most often used to implement memory-sensitive caches.

However, the Android implementation of `SoftReference` does not work like this: since [Android 9 as the garbage collector is more aggressive](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap) and the soft references are reclaimed almost immediately regardless of whether the device is low on memory.

***3. Use `LruCache`***

The [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference) advises against using `SoftReference` in a cache implementation and to use a `LruCache` instead. However, the `LruCache` poses some drawbacks.

Firstly, you have to specifying the maximum size of the cache. It isn’t obvious what to set the cache size to: ideally it’d just automatically be set as high as possible while still being a good citizen. If it’s set too small, it might be constantly reloading textures unnecessarily.

Secondly, a `Texture` may be removed from the cache which is currently in use and thus may be deleted from OpenGLES and then display as a missing texture to the user.

Is there a better way to maintain a cache of textures in OpenGL and be responsive to low memory scenarios (besides just deleting textures upon memory warnings)?

Comment: In case 3 you do you have to stick on standard implementation? You can write your own LRU cache with your own eviction policy. It can be something like case 1, but with LRU cache to tell you what should be evicted.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about best practices, large caches (that can take all the memory) with OpenGL ids for textures are rarely used. Actually it's worth to have only a few textures to render in the scene at one moment. More textures you have in the scene, more texture switches you need to do in frame. It costs. [Texture atlases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) were developed many years ago to reduce number of texture switches. However, atlases still can take a lot of memory.

With development of hardware capabilities and user expectations, texture atlases evolved into virtual/mega/sparse textures + texture data streaming for the cases of high memory usage. The idea is to use *virtual memory* approach and load/unload blocks of one very large texture in real-time. It has some drawbacks, good discussion about it can be found [here](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/questions/1768/how-can-virtual-texturing-actually-be-efficient). LRU cache can be built on top of it to tell what blocks are required at the moment.

Of course, engines can preload many textures (sparse or usual ones) and unload it after usage, e.g. as a part of dynamic loading of open world in a game. These textures aren't used for rendering simultaneously, and no one waits until they take all the memory to start unloading. The eviction algorithm here is highly dependant on particular app, even though maximum cache size in Mb is widely used practice here.

Comment: Unfortunately a texture atlas isn't a possible solution since the textures are user-supplied at runtime.